# How can I get an absolute URL instead of a relative one?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I use this code to give my images link, but this code gives me a relative URL

**MY Simplified Code :**

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="/upload/banner.jpg" width="374" height="60"></a>
```

how can I give an exact link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a protocol:

```
http://www.google.com/
```

The minimum required to make it domain-absolute is this:

```
//www.google.com/
```

which will use the same protocol as the current page (e.g. http or https).